# 'ssh -T git@github.com' says I am authenticated for the correct user, but running git commands says permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, version-control

I am trying to set up SSH key connections to github on an ubuntu server I'm running on digitalocean.

So far I've done the following:

- Generate SSH key on the ubuntu server at ~/.ssh/id_rsa with no passcode
- Added key to agent using `ssh-add id_rsa`
- In github, added the public key to user setting's SSH Keys

Logged into the server via SSH, I can run `ssh -T git@github.com` and I will get the response:

```
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub doesn't provide shell access
```

So then I attempt to pull from github and I get the following response:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I was thinking it's something to do with the shell access info but I think I've always done it this way! When I run `ssh -T git@github.com` locally I get the same info about git not allowing shell access, but it still allows me to do all the normal pull/push commands when I try them.

Does anyone have any advice?

--------- **edit** -------------------------

I believe this is an issue with sudo/non-sudo permissions. I need to run all of my git commands using sudo however my ssh key was not created with sudo so I think it had the wrong access permissions?

I attempted to create a new key using `sudo ssh-keygen`, however now I can't add it to my agent

If I run `eval 'ssh-agent'` normally then try to add the sudo generated key `ssh-add sudokey`, I get an error that I don't have permission to do anything to the key.

If I run `sudo ssh-add key` I get an error that it couldn't establish a connection to the agent

So then I think, open an agent under sudo by running `sudo eval 'ssh-agent'` however then I get the error `sudo: eval: command not found`

Comment: This implies that whatever you're running *on* the server does not have access to the key-pair. When you log in *to* the server and run things, you have given the server (and its ssh) access to your key-pair. What are you doing when you *don't* log in to the server, to give the server (and its ssh) access to your key-pair?

Comment: I think I figured out that it seems sudo does not have the same access to the key-pair that non-sudo user does. For example if i run `sudo ssh -T git@github.com` it will then not work. But how do I grant sudo access? I tried creating a new keypair using `sudo ssh key-generate` but i am still getting the same issue. it also won't allow me to ssh-add a sudo-created ssh key, and if i try `sudo ssh-add key` or `sudo eval 'ssh-agent'` i get an error that sudo eval is not a command

Comment: @torek I edited the post with what I tried

Comment: Ah - of course: `sudo` means *run as this other user*, and the other user is some *other user* with other permissions. Put the key into something *that* user can access, and maybe start up an ssh agent for that user. Note that sudo runs just one command. To run multiple commands, that one command needs to itself *be* a command that will run multiple commands. In general, though, the right way to use sudo is "don't use it": if there is some way to *not* use it, do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git comman
```

to check whats happening in background.